# Передача json с jsp в controller с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь передать json с вью в контроллер, но все время получаю 400 ошибку при методе  GET и 405 при методе POST. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему.

скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function searchText() {
                        var search = {
                            "pName": "bhanu",
                            "lName": "prasad"
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: "/admin/get",
                            data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log("SUCCESS: ", result);
                                alert("success");
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                console.log("ERROR: ", result);
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
          </script>
                <button id="but" type="button" onclick="searchText()"/>GO</li>
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/get",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestBody Search search, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String pName = search.getlName();
    String lName = search.getlName();


    System.out.println(pName+lName);
    // your logic next
    return "Success";
}
```

Класс Search:

```
public class Search {
private String pName;
private String lName;

public void setpName(String pName) {
    this.pName = pName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}

public String getpName() {
    return pName;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}
```

}

Comment: Может я не правильно понимаю технологию ajax и она не предназначается для передачи данных с клиента на сервер?

Comment: В итоге понял, что SpringSecurity не дает отработать ajax. Ссылается на невалидный crsf токен

Comment: Вроде с секъюрностью разобрался, но начало кидать слудеющую ошибку: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'pName': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function searchText() {
                        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
                        var header =$("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
                    var search = {
                        "pName": "bhanu",
                        "lName": "prasad"
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: "/admin/get",
                        data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                                // here it is
                                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                            },
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log("SUCCESS: ", result);
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            console.log("ERROR: ", result);
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
      </script>
            <button id="but" type="button" onclick="searchText()"/>GO</li>
```

В итоге решил проблему

Comment: Правда почему-то error срабатывает